# iOS set UISearchBar text programmatically

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I am trying to set the text of a UISearchBar programmatically but it isn't working for some reason.

```
[searchController.searchBar setText:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@", searchController.searchBar.text);
```

This returns null.

Comment: Have you verified that both `searchController` and `searchController.searchBar` are non-nil?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Search bar was nil. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it.